# Is it possible to set Bot Framework Composer Bots to a diffrernt lanugage? If not, when will this be availabe?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

i am working on a bot project with Microsofts Bot Framework. My bot is based on the SDK 4.0 and until this point, everything is working fine. In the last few days was thinking about making a change and go and use the BF Composer to configure and build my bot solutions.
After some tests i discovered, that the availible bots inside the Composer are only available in the english language set. But my bot uses german as the default language.

Now to my question:

***Is it possible to set Bot Framework Composer Bots  to a diffrernt lanugage than english (german for example)? If not, when will this be availabe?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer already supports authoring bots in different languages. The documentation on [multiple language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-use-multiple-language?tabs=v2x) should get you started. You can combine this with support for different cultures in LUIS and QnA to create bots in languages other than English.